# Cocoa calendar chooser

Tags: cocoa

My application uses the CalendarStore framework to add events to a specific calendar (chosen by the user during runtime) within iCal. I'm currently using NSPopupButton to display the list of calendars that are available by adding each object from `[[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] calendars]` to the popup.

My goal is to replicate the calendar chooser that shows up when importing an .ics file to iCal. Is there a built-in control for displaying calendars with their color, and separated into groups for each account (e.g. iCloud, On My Mac, or GMail calendar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in control, but you can combine an NSOutlineView in source list mode with an NSPopover control.